# What is wrong with my setText code?

Tags: android, textview

The purpose of this code is simple, when you open the app the default text is "hello word" and then you click the button to change to "app name" so when you click again it should go back to "hello word" but nothing happens at the second click.

```
TextView myText;
        String appName;
        String helloWord;
        String txt;
        myText = findViewById (R.id.mytext);
         appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
         helloWord = getResources().getString(R.string.helloWord);
         txt = myText.getText().toString();
          public void changeText(View v){
                if (txt.equals(helloWord)){
                    myText.setText(appName);
               }else if(txt.equals(appName)){
                    myText.setText(helloWord);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong ! The only thing wrong I see is your code . Where did you put this code ?? There is no life cycle method mentioned .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing the `TextView`'s text to the changing text.

variable `txt` is always `"hello world"` since it is only assigned at first time.

I your `changeText()` method, you should reassign `txt`.

```
public void changeText(View v){
    txt = myText.getText().toString();
    if (txt.equals(helloWord)){
        myText.setText(appName);
    }else if(txt.equals(appName)){
        myText.setText(helloWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Hyun I kim it worked. Before my txt variable was inside onCreate method.